# config.Check does not recognize context.Context as context.Context interface

Tags: go, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to execute types.Config.Check on `github.com/OrlovEvgeny/go-mcache/mcache.go` in order to extract the definitions and types in the Go file.

The problem is that the Check() method fails with:

```
cannot use ctx (variable of type context.Context) as context.Context value in argument to gcmap.NewGC: context.Context does not implement context.Context (wrong type for method Deadline)
                        have Deadline() (deadline time.Time, ok bool)
                        want Deadline() (deadline time. Time, ok bool)
```

The Context used in mcache library is quite standard, and is passed to NewGC():

```
func (mc *CacheDriver) initStore() (context.Context, context.CancelFunc) {
    ctx, finish := context.WithCancel(context. Background())
    mc.storage = safeMap.NewStorage()
    mc.gc = gcmap.NewGC(ctx, mc.storage) // <-- The problem is here
    return ctx, finish
}
```

I should also point out the library compiles successfully and works.

I have debugged the issue it ultimately the following line returns false (`types/predicates. go:416`):

```
return x.obj == y.obj
```

I have compared the two object, but they seem similar besides their `token.Pos`, which I guess it is the reason why it returns false.
[image]

Does anyone has any idea what am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: which `context` are you importing? I guess you are using old package `golang.org/x/net/context`.

Comment: @N.F. - The mcache package writes 'import "context"'

Comment: @N.F. - it looks like I don't even have that context in the GOROOT.... I am using go 1.18.6